# How can I solve GPU rendering issue?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I have a **AMD r7 370 GPU**, and an Intel i5 4460 CPI. I am using blender **2.78** (openCL enabled, downloaded from GraphicAll). My problem is I can't get the original color and output from GPU rendering, while CPU provides accurate color. GPU render shows the diffuse materials emitting colors, 'blue' in my case. and emitting materials starting to emit yellow. both instead of white which is set as the color.

**CPU rendered:**
[image: appropriate color, no extra color emission from 'diffused material']

That has appropriate color, no extra color emission from 'diffused material'.

**GPU rendered:**
[image: Extra colors and materials not behaving the way they should]

Extra colors and materials not behaving the way they should.

Comment: Have you tried rendering with a current version of blender?

Comment: my graphics card is GCN 1 , officially it doesn't have support for GPU rendering. Buying a new GPU now is not an option.

Comment: 2.79 release log says "Due to various issues with drivers for AMD GCN 1.0 architecture, those cards are no longer supported for Cycles rendering " so, you may have hit one of those issues, perhaps...?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've already identified your problem: Your card isn't officially supported. Combine that with a non official build and it's not surprising to run into errors every now and then.

You can check out the blender wiki article on AMD cards for more info: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL

The wiki article directly says that GCN 1.0 cards aren't supported in builds after March 2017 and that 2.78c (available form https://blender.org) should be used if you have one of those cards. It also says that the limitations are considered a TODO rather than a bug.

Basically there are known limitations with Blender's interaction with certain cards, and unfortunately you have one of them. You should definitely give the latest builds a try to see if anything has been updated, and there is a GPU+CPU option in the newest builds that might be worth checking out.